# geotools shapefile does not support utf-8 for dbf header

Tags: shapefile, java, geotools, dbf, utf-8

I create a ShapefileDataStore to create a new shapefile and call dataStore.createSchema(...) . But it does not work for utf-8 header fields.
I checked the geotools source code and realized that it does not support utf-8.

```
org.geotools.data.shapefile.dbf.DbaseFileHeader.java

public void writeHeader(...) throws IOException{

  ...
  line  844:
  buffer.put((byte)fields[i].fieldName.charAt(j));
  ...
}
```

How can I create a new shapefile with desired utf-8 header fields?

**note:** The shapefile plugin can read utf-8 header fields but it cannot write them in utf-8 !

Comment: DBF (III) files were never designed to support anything but ASCII - if you would like to submit a fix please read the developer's guide (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/developer/) or you could purchase comercial support for this issue.

Comment: But I saw QGIS can write dbf files with utf-8 encoding. But dbf header can only contain field names with maximum of 10 characters. In utf-8 it evaluates to 5 characters.

Comment: as I said DBF files aren't designed for modern computing, try to avoid using them

Comment: Yes sir !!!!!!!!